# Hyperbolic function in Second Order DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please find attached a snap. Can anyone show me the steps of getting equation 3.15 solved to equation 3.17?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s61vn.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Your ODE is: $$y''=\xi^2y.$$ 
You can use Eulers exponential ansatz $y=\exp(\lambda x)$ plug this into the ODE to get:

$$(\lambda^2-\xi^2)\exp(\lambda x)=0.$$

This can only be true if $\lambda^2=\xi^2$, as $\exp(\lambda x)\neq 0$. So we obtain $\lambda_{1/2}=\pm \xi$. We found two linearly independent solutions for the ODE. In order to construct the general solution we use linear combinations of these solutions:

$y(x)=c_1\exp(\xi x)+c_2\exp(-\xi x).$

Use the boundary condtions to determine $c_1$ and $c_2$. Can you complete it from here?

If you rewrite $c_1=a_1/2+b_1/2$ and $c_2 = a_1/2-b_1/2$ you can obtain:
$$y(x)=a_1(\exp(\xi x)+\exp(-\xi x))/2+b_1(\exp(\xi x)-\exp(-\xi x))/2.$$

The expressions in the bracket are nothing but $\cosh(\xi x)$ and $\sinh(\xi x)$.